# How to get the way form current position to a specified position (x, y) in a map

Tags: python, graph

I am working on python with Nao by Aldebaran. I want to let it move to its position to a specified position. Nao has in memory a map of the house. It's a matrix named map and `map[x][y]` points out a 1m x 1m square inside the house, some squares are obstacles so Nao can't walk on them. There some squares where there are the doors too. I need to make Nao move to a specified position (x, y), and if it's in another room I think the doors coordinates could be useful, but I don't know how to use them. How can I obtain the best way without bruteforcing?

Comment: A*? Djikstra's algorithm? There's a whole category of study based on the problem of [pathfinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding). Good news: you've got a lot to choose from. Bad news: you've got a lot to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy already has functions to do this.

Try [scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html) or [scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html)